# Sorting an list of object in descending order

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I want to sort a list object in descending order, and facing classCastException.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

     class Student implements Comparator<Student>{
     private int id;
         private String name;

        public Student(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

}

public class CollectionSearchDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(new Student(3, "ouier"));
    list.add(new Student(2, "fdgds"));
    list.add(new Student(7, "kiluf"));
    list.add(new Student(1, "6trfd"));
    list.add(new Student(8, "hjgas"));
    list.add(new Student(5, "ewwew"));

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {

            return arg0.getId() - arg1.getId();
        }
    });

    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Student student = (Student) iterator.next();
        System.out.print(student.getId()+":"+student.getName()+" ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nSorting in reverse order:");

//  Collections.reverse(list);
    Comparator<Student> collections = Collections.reverseOrder();
    Collections.sort(list, collections);     // here getting classCastException.

    Iterator iterator1 = list.iterator();
    while(iterator1.hasNext()){
        Student student = (Student) iterator1.next();
        System.out.print(student.getId()+":"+student.getName()+" ");
    }
}

}
```

Want to know few thigs.
1)what is difference bet'n 
         Collection.reverse(list) 
     and 
         Comparator collections = Collections.reverseOrder();
         Collections.sort(list, collections);
2)why i am facing classCastException.

Comment: You're getting a `ClassCastException` because `Student` should implement `Comparable<Student>`, not `Comparator<Student>`.

Comment: yes.it works.Can you please let me know with little more description?It will help me to understand this concept better

Comment: A `Comparator` compares things.  A `Comparable` can be compared to other things.

Comment: Hi,I want to perform binarySearch on this list.I am facing an exception.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896120/facing-exception-in-implementation-of-binarysearch-method  .Please help me out.I request you

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `reverse()`  method,

`reverseOrder()`

> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface.

so the `ClassCastException`